# Python: Save element by element from input

Tags: python, string, file, input

I have an input file as follow

```
0.1 #real number
0.2 #real number
Hello #string
10000 #integer number
```

I want to read it and use each line, before the '#' symbol, in my code. For the second part I did

```
with open('input.dat') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split('#', 1)[0]
        line = line.rstrip()
        print(line) #test print
f.close()
```

In this case I can read and print the number/string before the '#' symbol, but what about save them?
For instance if I want to save 'Hello' in a string called 'name', '0.1' as a real called 'min' and so on.
The simplest way I found, to read the input.dat file and save the elements as I want is

```
with open('input.dat') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

min=lines[2] # it print me: "0.1 #real number"
```

But what about only `min=0.1`, how can I obtain both the reading and saving procedure ? I am noob in python so maybe I lack of basics.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have all the pieces, you just need to put them in the right places:

```
def remove_comment(line):
    line = line.split('#', 1)[0]
    line = line.rstrip()
    return line

with open('input.dat') as f:
    lines = [remove_comment(line) for line in f]

# no need for this: "with" takes care of it: # f.close()

min=lines[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to store the results in an array. What to do next will depend on how your input is structured: will it always contain just four values of those types and in that order?

```
values = []
with open('input.dat') as f:
    for line in f:
        value = line.split('#', 1)[0]

        if value.isdigit():
            values.append(int(value))
        else:
            try:
                values.append(float(value))
            except ValueError:
                values.append(value)
```

If the values always appear in that order, you can then do something like this:

```
n_min, n_max, name, big_number = values
```

(note: try to avoid naming variables `min`, `max` or other built-in keywords since that might cause problems later on!)